# source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Я пытаюсь собрать проект на java 8, указав в качестве цели java 6:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Project settings:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

General IDE (Java compiler) settings:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но получаю ошибку:

> javacTask: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8

Как можно исправить эту ошибку? Или же нельзя собрать проект для 6-ой джавы на 8-ой джаве?

Comment: Указать `source` тоже 1.6.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, тогда будет ошибка компиляции - проект написан с использованием лямбд, а переписывать код не хочется)

Comment: никак, только переписывать

Comment: Если так нужны лямбды можете посмотреть на Kotlin, он может компилироваться в 1.6 или 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Или же нельзя собрать проект для 6-ой джавы на 8-ой джаве?

Собрать можно, но для этого нужно указать соответствующую версию исходного кода (1.6). Соответственно, в этом случае нельзя будет использовать возможности языка, появившиеся после 6-й версии.

Компилятор  требует, чтобы версия виртуальной машины была не ниже версии исходного кода. Из [документации javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> **-target version**
>   Generates class files that target a specified release of the virtual machine. **Class files will run on the specified target and on later releases, but not on earlier releases of the JVM.**

Обосновано это тем, что для компиляции новых возможностей языка (лямбда-выражения, методы по умолчанию) используются новые возможности виртуальной машины, которых нет на старых версиях.

Кроме этого между версиями есть различия в стандартной библиотеке. Например, в пакет [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) появился в JDK 8, соответственно, ни один из этих классов использовать на старых версиях не получится.

Можете попробовать изучить проект [RetroLambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda), который подстраивает лямбда-выражения под Java 7. Либо попробовать частично или полностью перейти на Kotlin, как предложил @Bleser в комментариях.

Технически можно использовать другие компиляторы, либо вручную переписать версию в заголовка уже скомпилированных файлов. Но использовать таким образом лямбды на старых версиях виртуальной машины не получится. Теоретически так можно добиться ограниченного запуска на старых версиях, т.е. проект будет определять версию среды исполнения и не будет загружать классы, использующие новые возможности, на старых версиях. Этот подход достаточно неудобный и, скорее всего, легче будет разбить проект на модули, с поддержкой разных версий.

Близкие по теме вопросы на английском:

- [Can Java 8 code be compiled to run on Java 7 JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143684/can-java-8-code-be-compiled-to-run-on-java-7-jvm?rq=1)
- [Are compiled Java 8 lambda expressions backwards compatible with earlier versions of the Java runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572230/are-compiled-java-8-lambda-expressions-backwards-compatible-with-earlier-version)
- [How will Java lambda functions be compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827262/how-will-java-lambda-functions-be-compiled)
- [Are there any specific examples of backward incompatibilities between Java versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654923/are-there-any-specific-examples-of-backward-incompatibilities-between-java-versi)